# Css. Верстка чата. Как прижать сообщения чата вниз беседы

Tags: css, вёрстка

```css
.chat-client-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
}

.chat-client-conversation {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.chat-client-conversation__message {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.chat-client-conversation__message-body {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 13px 8px 13px;
  background: #dedede;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-client-header"></div>
<div class="chat-client-body">
  <div class="chat-client-conversation">

    <div class="chat-client-conversation__message" id="message-23632">
      <div class="chat-client-conversation__message-body">
        <p>Текст первого сообщения</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-client-conversation__message" id="message-23633">
      <div class="chat-client-conversation__message-body">
        <p>Текст второго сообщения</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="chat-client-footer"></div>
```

Делаю чат. 
При добавлении первых сообщений в тело чата (".chat-client-conversation") нужно их (сообщения - ".chat-client-conversation__message") прижимать к низу беседы. Использовать флекс нельзя. JS на самый крайний случай. 
Лучшим решением будет чистый CSS. Какие варианты есть?

Comment: код вставить в вопрос не хочешь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопрос.

Comment: можно чат развернуть на 180 градусов и сообщения тоже на 180 ;)

Comment: Что значит развернуть на 180 градусов? Если имеется ввиду, что поле ввода переместить в header и сообщения тем самым должны "липнуть" к верху - не вариант. Противоречит техническому заданию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `position: absolute`:

```css
.chat-client-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  background: wheat;
}

.chat-client-conversation {
  padding: 0 12px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.chat-client-conversation__message {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.chat-client-conversation__message-body {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 13px 8px 13px;
  background: #dedede;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-client-header"></div>
<div class="chat-client-body">
  <div class="chat-client-conversation">

    <div class="chat-client-conversation__message" id="message-23632">
      <div class="chat-client-conversation__message-body">
        <p>Текст первого сообщения</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-client-conversation__message" id="message-23633">
      <div class="chat-client-conversation__message-body">
        <p>Текст второго сообщения</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="chat-client-footer"></div>
```

Comment: Неожиданно, но это то что нужно. Мне казалось, с "position: absolute" я наигрался со всеми возможными вариантами. Но прописав высоту через "max-height" все стало как и должно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/vertical-align

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Думаю вам подойдет

Comment: Или не подойдёт. Мы до сих пор не знаем, какое тело к какому низу нужно прижимать, а vertical-align работает далеко не везде

Comment: Свойство vertical-align: bottom; не решает задачи. Сообщения не "липнут" к низу чата.

Comment: `display: table-cell` к этому варианту нужно добавить

Comment: Почти то что нужно. Сообщения прижимаются книзу чата, но при свойстве у родителя "display: table-cell", внутри этого родителя нельзя скролить  если высота сообщений суммарно больше высоты родителя. Иными словами нельзя проскролить по всем сообщениям чата. Свойство "overflow: scroll" не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

```
Свойству .chat-client-conversation__message задаётся значение bottom: -100px; (или top: 100px;)
У меня всё работает - https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/qXKRjY
```

Comment: Ваш пример оторван от реальности. Во-первых, когда сообщение всего одно, оно всё ещё не прижато к низу. Во-вторых, когда сообщений много, вверху остаётся ненужная пустота

Comment: И да, пример должен находиться прямо в ответе, а не по ссылке